# Show Images In List View - OpenERP Web-Client

Tags: listview, odoo

Is that possible to show the images in list view for OpenERP Web-client...?

Comment: Which list view? Which image? You have to be more specific

Comment: Product Images or Employee images on the list view(tree view).

Answer (score 3):

In v6.0 tree views can display buttons with icons.
For document images you need to wait for the  web client on v6.1. 
It features a new ["kanban" view](https://plus.google.com/photos/114651851090973498921/albums/5691494542481855361)  that is able to display an image on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try with buttons now and Kanban View is good, I Will wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with OE Web Client 6.1 you can do it with kanban very easily or even you can create some web addons and inherit the list view implementation and you can definetly add the same link to the OE Web Addons is [Document Web Addons](http://planet.domsense.com/docs/openerp-web/en/index.html). But sadly you can do it 6.0 web client.

Regards